# How to change <Nav.Link> text color in React?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I have tried everything possible(inline, another CSS file you name it) but nothing seems to work.

I am trying to make a Navbar using React bootstrap.

This one: https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/navbar/

Here's my code:

```
import React from 'react';
import './Navbar.css';
import Logo from './Logo.png';
import { Nav, Navbar, NavDropdown, FormControl, Button, Form } from "react-bootstrap";

const Nabar=()=>{
    return(

        <Navbar fixed="top" expand="sm" >

            <Navbar.Brand href="/">
            <img 
                src={Logo}
                style={{width:'10em', Height:'10em'}}
                className="d-inline-block align-top"
                alt="Youth Math Logo"
            />
            </Navbar.Brand>

            <Navbar.Toggle aria-controls="basic-navbar-nav" />

            <Navbar.Collapse id="basic-navbar-nav">
                <Nav className="mr-auto">

//------------------------Over Here-----------------------------------------------------------------
                    <Nav.Link className="home" href="#home">Home</Nav.Link>
                    <Nav.Link href="#link">Link</Nav.Link>
                    <NavDropdown title="Dropdown" id="basic-nav-dropdown">
                        <NavDropdown.Item href="#action/3.1">Action</NavDropdown.Item>
                        <NavDropdown.Item href="#action/3.2">Another action</NavDropdown.Item>
                        <NavDropdown.Item href="#action/3.3">Something</NavDropdown.Item>
                        <NavDropdown.Divider />
                        <NavDropdown.Item href="#action/3.4">Separated link</NavDropdown.Item>
                    </NavDropdown>
                </Nav>
                <Form inline>
                    <FormControl type="text" placeholder="Search" className="mr-sm-2" />
                    <Button variant="outline-success">Search</Button>
                </Form>
            </Navbar.Collapse>

        </Navbar>
    );
}

export default Nabar;
```

I want to change it's color from default to white.

Comment: Give it an actual `className` and try adding `!important` to the style you apply as in `color: white !important`

Comment: Doesn't work, gave it `className="home" `  and tried `.home{color: white !important;}`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of `<Nav.Link href="#link">Link</Nav.Link>`

write

`<Nav.Link href="#link"><h4 className="linkText">Link</h4></Nav.Link>`

Followed by CSS

`.linkText{ color: white ; }`

Answer (score 10):

> Try this:

```css
  .nav-link{
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    color: #2699FB !important;
  }
```

> inside "{}" put what you want, do not forget the "!important"

Answer (score 3):

This may be too late. But may help someone in the future. Override this bootstrap CSS class.

```
 .navbar-dark .navbar-nav .nav-link
{
    color:#fff;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Late to the party but this done the trick for me

```
 <Nav.Link href="/" style={{color:"white"}}>Log out</Nav.Link>
```